# variable undefined when get data from json_encode (Function PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want get value from php file, so I call json_encode function in my php script. but when i get value using javascript the result is undefined.

I am using codeigniter and javascript.

**Javascript**

```
var sisa = (persentasevco / 100) * (jumlahvco)
document.getElementById('periodetk').value = periodetk
var totalt = sisa * periodet
$.ajax({
  url: '<?=base_url(\'lahan/convertString/\')?>' + totalt,
  success: function (data) {
    document.getElementById('persediaanvco').value = data.hasil
  },
})
```

**PHP**

```php
public function convertString($value){
    $hasil = number_format($value,2,',','.');
    echo json_encode($hasil);
}
```

I want send $hasil from php to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just sending a string (the output from `number_format`), you don't need to `json_encode` it.

**PHP**

```php
public function convertString($value){
    echo number_format($value,2,',','.'); // Echo directly
    die(); // End script
}
```

**JS**

```js
var sisa = (persentasevco / 100) * (jumlahvco)
document.getElementById('periodetk').value = periodetk
var totalt = sisa * periodet
$.ajax({
  url: '<?=base_url(\'lahan/convertString/\')?>' + totalt,
  success: function (data) {
    document.getElementById('persediaanvco').value = data
  },
})
```